# Why is backpressure important with RxJava when the Publisher and Subscriber are on the same Thread?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, publish-subscribe, reactive-streams

Take the following `RxJava` code:

```
public class IntervalObserverTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(10);
        IntervalPublisher o = new IntervalPublisher();

        o.getPublisher().subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {

            volatile Subscription s;
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
                this.s = s;
                s.request(10);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(String s) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                latch.countDown();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable t) {
                s.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
            }
        });

        if(!latch.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
}

class IntervalPublisher {

    public Publisher<String> getPublisher() {
        return Flowable.range(1, 100)
                .map(String::valueOf)
                .delay(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .delaySubscription(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

It simply prints the thread name on the `onNext()` call.

Here `onNext()` is actually called by the same thread which runs the Publisher(Flowable):

```
RxComputationThreadPool-2
```

This means that the same thread which runs the `Publisher` is the same thread on the `Subscriber` side. As is expected.

My question is then of **what use is the backpressure setting ?**

**There is no way the Subscriber can be overloaded since their is just ONE thread doing the whole thing.** Correct me if I am wrong.

**In general, what use is the backpressure setting ?**

The only use I can think of is when the `Publisher` and `Subscriber` is on different threads and the `Subscriber` maybe sees that it has a lot of backed up requests in its buffer and decides to tell the `Publisher` to stop producing.

This the **classic Producer Consumer problem with a bounded queue**. But this has no meaning when the Publisher and the Subscriber is on the same Thread.

Am I correct ?

Comment: It could still be used as a mechanism to limit the number of subscriber requests that are processed per batch, for instance if you have a large amount of data you're processing to display.  Instead of having it all just "pop" in, you could display partial results in batches.  I think the paradigm still generally makes more sense in an asynchronous context, though.

Comment: But there is no chance of overload. Since there is just 1 thread.

Comment: If there the producer is on the same thread than the consumer, then backpressure has no practical effect. The moment though the flow wanders between multiple threads, backpressure is essential to limit the internal buffer sizes.
See also https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#which-type-to-use